# PDComboBox marked as Read Only is not visible in PDF document

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

I am generating a custom PDF file and marking a PDComboBox as read-only if the value is set in code during document generation, otherwise the user can choose between the set values. However, when viewing the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader, the space where the read-only PDComboBox should be is blank.

```
private void addTapeColorComboBox(final int rowIndex, final PDRectangle rectangle) throws IOException {
        PDComboBox comboBox = new PDComboBox(currentForm);
        List<String> values = Arrays.stream(TapeColor.values()).map(TapeColor::getAbbreviation).collect(Collectors.toList());
        comboBox.setOptions(values);
        comboBox.setDefaultAppearance(TEXT_FIELD_DEFAULT_APPEARANCE);
        comboBox.setPartialName(TAPE + rowIndex);
        currentForm.getFields().add(comboBox);

        PDAnnotationWidget widget = comboBox.getWidgets().get(0);
        widget.setRectangle(rectangle);
        widget.setPage(currentPage);
        widget.setPrinted(true);
        currentPage.getAnnotations().add(widget);

        PDActionJavaScript tapeColorJavaScript = new PDActionJavaScript(""
                + "if (event.value==\"R\") {"
                + "    event.target.fillColor = color.red;"
                + "} else if (event.value==\"G\") {"
                + "    event.target.fillColor = color.green;"
                + "} else if (event.value==\"Y\") {"
                + "    event.target.fillColor = color.yellow;"
                + "} else {"
                + "    event.target.fillColor = color.white;"
                + "}"
        );

        PDFormFieldAdditionalActions actions = new PDFormFieldAdditionalActions();
        actions.setV(tapeColorJavaScript);
        actions.setF(tapeColorJavaScript);
        comboBox.setActions(actions);
    }

tapes.get(rowCounter).setValue(tapeColor.getAbbreviation());
tapes.get(rowCounter).setReadOnly(true);
```

If the setReadOnly function is false, then the document and output work as desired. If true, then the document and output are blank.

Comment: Hello, please link to your PDF (or include enough calling code to create it, just assume that we're all lazy) and tell what PDFBox version you are using.